# How to Translate CSV Data into TFRecord Files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tensorflow

Currently I am working on a system that can take data from a CSV file and import it into a TFRecord file, However I have a few questions.

For starters, I need to know what type a TFRecord file can take, when using CSV types are removed.

Secondly, How can I convert data type:object into a type that a TFRecord can take?

I have two columns (will post example below) of two objects types that are strings, How can I convert that data to the correct type for TFRecords?

When importing Im hoping to append data from each row at a time into the TFRecord file, any advice or documentation would be great, I have been looking for some time at this problem and it seems there can only be ints,floats inputted into a TFRecord but what about a list/array of Integers?

Thankyou for reading!

Quick Note, I am using PANDAS to create a dataframe of the CSV file

Some Example Code Im using

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()


def Start():
    db = pd.read_csv("I:\Github\ClubKeno\Keno Project\Database\..\LotteryDatabase.csv")

    pd.DataFrame = db
    print(db['Winning_Numbers'])
    print(db.dtypes)

    training_dataset = (
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
            (
                tf.cast(db['Draw_Number'].values, tf.int64),
                tf.cast(db['Winning_Numbers'].values, tf.int64),
                tf.cast(db['Extra_Numbers'].values, tf.int64),
                tf.cast(db['Kicker'].values, tf.int64)
            )
        )
    )

    for features_tensor, target_tensor in training_dataset:
        print(f'features:{features_tensor} target:{target_tensor}')
```

Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

[CSV Data](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/502661247809093673/626946732239880194/LotteryDatabase.csv)

Update:
Got Two Columns of dating working using the following function...

```py
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        file_pattern=databasefile,
        column_names=['Draw_Number', 'Kicker'],
        column_defaults=[tf.int64, tf.int64],
    )
```

However when trying to include my two other column object types
(What data looks like in both those columns)
`"3,9,11,16,25,26,28,29,36,40,41,46,63,66,67,69,72,73,78,80"`

I get an error, here is the function I tried for that

```py
    dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        file_pattern=databasefile,
        column_names=['Draw_Number', 'Winning_Numbers', 'Extra_Numbers', 'Kicker'],
        column_defaults=[tf.int64, tf.compat.as_bytes, tf.compat.as_bytes, tf.int64],
        header=True,
        batch_size=100,
        field_delim=',',
        na_value='NA'
    )
```

This Error Appears:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'function'> to Tensor. Contents: <function as_bytes at 0x000000EA530908C8>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Should I try to Cast those two types outside the function and try combining it later into the TFRecord file alongside the tf.data from the `make_csv_dataset` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For starters, I need to know what type a TFRecord file can take, when using CSV types are removed.

TFRecord accepts following datatypes-
string, byte, float32, float 64, bool, enum, int32, int64, uint32, uint64
Talked [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/tf_records#data_types_for_tfexample).

> Secondly, How can I convert data type:object into a type that a TFRecord can take?

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/tf_records#creating_a_tfexample_message) is an example from TF, it is a bit complicated to digest it at once but if you read it carefully it is easy.

> have two columns (will post example below) of two objects types that are strings, How can I convert that data to the correct type for TFRecords?

For string type data, you require `tf.train.BytesList` which returns a bytes_list from a string.

> When importing Im hoping to append data from each row at a time into the TFRecord file, any advice or documentation would be great, I have been looking for some time at this problem and it seems there can only be ints,floats inputted into a TFRecord but what about a list/array of Integers?
>
> Quick Note, I am using PANDAS to create a dataframe of the CSV file

Instead of reading csv file using Pandas, I would recommend you to use `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset` defined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset). This will make this conversion process very faster than Pandas and will give you less compatibility issues to work with TF classes. If you use this function, then you will not need to read the csv file row by row but all at once using `map()` which uses `eager execution`. [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/tf_records#tfrecord_files_using_tfdata) is a good tutorial to get started.

Accidentally edited wrong section of the post

Comment: I looked at all the documentation you posted and I want to say thank you for all of it!

When looking at using the `tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset' function It has to input all Columns unless you use the select_columns attribute which allows only passing in columns you want to use, However I have two columns of string type that I would have to convert to `tf.train.BytesList` first and then append into the `make_csv_dataset` function. How would I go about doing this? I post an update of what the CSV file looks like, thanks for reading

Comment: You are saying you have two columns in different csv files, so you can add these two columns together and save it as a csv file, then just call this file using `make_csv_file` which will give you tf.data type output and then you can use [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/tf_records#tfrecord_files_using_tfdata) procedure. Remember `from_tensor_slices` also outputs tf.data type dataset.

Comment: No I have one CSV file that contains two columns of object type that looks like this:`"3,9,11,16,25,26,28,29,36,40,41,46,63,66,67,69,72,73,78,80"`
I need too Input these two columns of object type and two other columns of int type and be able to form that into something that tf.data would accept, from earlier it sounded like I could use a map once all the values are non object type and then input that into tf.data. Would that work?

Comment: So, after you convert these two string type columns why do you want to append it to `make_csv_dataset`? What you will get from after converting to `BytesList` has to be stored as TFRecord file!

Comment: So do I apply all my columns to the `make_csv_dataset`? and at this point I should no longer be using pandas? im going to experiment with it more but im sure it gave me warnings earlier about not being the correct type when implementing

Thankyou for taking time for helping me with this, im sorry if im not fully understanding

Comment: Update:

I was able to get the make_csv_dataset function working, with my two integer data types, my other two column types that are string type but really look like this
`"3,9,11,16,25,26,28,29,36,40,41,46,63,66,67,69,72,73,78,80"` give me an error when I include those to the `make_csv_dataset()' here is my function so far:
(Posted above)